# ORA-00979 Group by clause error

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute a SQL command

`select distinct T1.dbid,T1.id,T6.user_name,T6.action_name,T6.action_timestamp,T2.filename from promotion T1,history T6,attachments T2 where T1.dbid = T6.entity_dbid  and 16777433 = T6.entitydef_id  and T1.dbid = T2.entity_dbid  (+)  and 16777962 = T2.entity_fielddef_id (+)  and (T1.dbid <> 0 and ((T6.action_name = 'Add-Comments-Attachments' and T6.action_timestamp between to_date('2021-03-24 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and  to_date('2022-03-23 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))))  group by T1.dbid order by T1.id ASC ,T6.action_timestamp ASC`

which gives me `ORA 00979` error message and I cannot figure how to over come it.
I tried to use `STRING_AGG(T1.id, ',')` as `T1.id`  etc... i.e with each variable (column) as I saw somewhere but again in vain. The result I wish to get is to narrow the number of lines to 1 which will group together the lines in column 1 (`T1.id`) and list the results of in each column also in 1 line. Any ideas how to resolve it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Might be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are answers on Stack Overflow: [ORA-00979 not a group by expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520608/1115360).

Comment: First thanks for your answers and help. So here are some clarifications. My table consists of several columns in which the values are strings e.g. user name or file name or date so SUM or AVG etc... is of no use when adding the other columns into the GROUP BY. So how do I group or "join" the rows of the same ID into 1 in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see, ORA-00979 means "not a GROUP BY expression."

And the "group by" clause should contain all of the expression that are in the "select" clause, which is not your case.

I would suggest to fix this first.

Source :
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm

Answer (score 0):

You must put all columns of the SELECT in the GROUP BY.
Columns which are not included in the GROUP BY must use group functions,
so they can give a single value (COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM, SVG).

Aa an example take this simple database table:

```
FOO BAR
0   11
0   22
```

And execute the command:

```
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY FOO
```

The result must be a single row.

Now we know that the first column `FOO`  has to contain `0` because of the
GROUP BY, but for the second column `BAR` there are now two values to chose
from. Which result would you expect for the second column: 11 or 22?

This would be solved by assigning the second column a group function like:

```
SELECT FOO, SUM(BAR) FROM table GROUP BY FOO
```

Now the result is one nice row with the value of "(0, 33)".